# Unable to access Kibana on AWS EC2 instance using url

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, kibana, elk

I have Elasticseasrch and Kibana installed on EC2 instance where I am able to access Elasticsearch using on this url `http://public-ip/9200`. But I am unable to access Kibana using `http://public-ip/5601`.

I have configured `kibana.yml` and added certain fields.

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: 0.0.0.0
elasticsearch.url: 0.0.0.0:9200
```

On doing `wget http://localhost:5601` I am getting below output:

```
--2022-06-10 11:23:37--  http://localhost:5601/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5601... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 83731 (82K) [text/html]
 Saving to: ‘index.html’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you open port `5601` in the security group?

Comment: Yeah I did I opened `5601` and `9200` port having TCP protocol access from anywhere.

Comment: do you get timeout or some other problem?

Comment: It's usually http://ip:port, maybe you can try if this helps "http://public-ip:5601"

Comment: @ChethanL yeah I am doing that only but its showing site can't be reached

Comment: @Digvijay can you share your kibana logs ??

Comment: Since you mentioned already that the respective port is open, maybe you can execute below on the EC2 machine to make sure if Kibana service is running fine

`wget http://localhost:5601`

Comment: @Amit where I can find kibana logs

Comment: @Digvijay can you show your kibana.yml config ? there if you have configured logs would go to that location otherwise default location , meanwhile can you share the output of what Chethan mentioned ??

Comment: @ChethanL on doing `wget http://localhost:5601` I am getting response that I have updated in my post above .

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -nltpu` ?

Answer (score 0):

Server Host set to `0.0.0.0` means it should be accessible from outside localhost but double check that the listener is actually listening for external connections on that port using `netstat -nltpu`. The server is also accessible on it's public IP on port 9200 so try the following:

- EC2 Security Group should inbound TCP traffic on that port 5601 from your IP address.
- Network ACLs should allow inbound/outbound TCP traffic on port 5601.
- OS firewall ( e.g. `ufw` or `firewalld` ) should allow traffic on that port. You can run `iptables -L -nxv` to check the firewall rules.
- Try connecting to that port from a different EC2 instance in the same VPC. It is possible that what ever internet connection you are using may have a firewall blocking connections on that port. This is common with corporate firewalls.
- If these fail, next you want to check if the packets are reaching your EC2 instance so you can run a packet capture on that port using `tcpdump -ni any port 5601` and check if you have any packets coming in/out on that port.
- if you don't see any packets on `tcpdump`, use [VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) to see if packets are coming in/out that port.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the kibana port (5601 ) is open via security groups

I could able to resolve the issue by updating config `server.host:localhost` to `server.host:0.0.0.0`
and `elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]` (in my case kibana and ES both are running on the same machine) in kibana.yml

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-url-gives-connection-refused-from-outside-machine/122067/8